# Plyer spamming system tray with processes for every notification

Tags: python, windows, kivy

I've made a program in Python that monitors the user's distance from their face to their webcam and sends a notification using Plyer if they're too close. The problem is that every time it sends a notification, the system tray gains another process and after a long time it gets flooded. I do not know why this behavior happens. Is this what Plyer is supposed to do?

Minimal reproductible example:

```
from time import sleep
from plyer import notification


# send a notification every second
while True:
    sleep(1)
    notification.notify(
            title='You are too close to the monitor!',
            message='Please stand further away from your monitor!',
            app_icon=None,  # e.g. 'C:\\icon_32x32.ico'
            # TODO: Get an icon
            timeout=1,  # seconds
        )
```

[Screenshot from my system tray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sryj3.png)

Has anyone else encountered this kind of strange behavior?
Thanks for any response.

Comment: You already asked this yesterday @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70563017/plyer-spamming-system-tray-with-processes-for-every-notification and instead of editing to improve your question you just ask the same thing again with no further details!

Comment: I closed the previous thread because I wanted the title. I have modified the example to be as minimal as possible(even ran it from the Python Console, no script needed) and added a screenshot of the effect of running said code. I honestly cannot conjure any further information because there is nothing else to it. The question is more adressed to people who have also encountered the issue and possibly found a resolution. I would add an issue to plyer's devs on their repository, but I can't really find it. Sorry for the long reply, but please be more specific in what you want, not just complain.

Answer (score 0):

Used notify-py module instead of plyer.notification for sending notifications to users. Problem was solved.
I do not recommend using plyer for this.